# Using Restlet with Apache2

Tags: servlets, apache2, port, restlet-2.0, apache2-module

I'm a newbie here..I'm trying to build a simple single page web application

for now I am using apache 2 http server to serve the front end stuff(html/js/css/imgs..)
and using a jar that uses Restlet2.0 on port 8015 to provide APIS for Ajax calls from the front end

now because Apache is using port 80 and Restlet is using port 8015, I have to use absolute address in my ajax calls where all cross-domain hell breaks lose

I'm wondering how do I make Apache 2 work with Restlet? I've been googling a lot and there has not been many useful results. How can I forward all the API calls to Restlet, and still taking advantage of the nice apache 2 features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to setup a reverse HTTP proxy with Apache HTTPd (recommended).

An alternative is to use the AJP protocol as Restlet supports it through its Jetty extension.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html

Comment: thanks a lot! I did some poking and the reserve HTTP proxy is exactly what i was looking for, got everything working